# undefined method for nil class in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting the above error message when trying to view data from my model in my view (the index page of my controller)

my controller

```
 def index

 @recipe = Recipe.all

 end
```

my view

```
   <% @recipes.each do |r| %>
   <tr><td><%= r.dish_name %></td></tr>
    <% end %>
```

Im new to rails so maybe doing this completely wrong. Could someone also explain what the error means?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found my error. my controller needed to be

@recipes = Recipe.all

I didn’t pluralize my recipe object